# Java NIO - non-blocking channels vs AsynchronousChannels

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio, channel

Java NIO offers `SocketChannel` and `ServerSocketChannel` which can be set to non-blocking mode (asynchronous). Most of the operations return a value that corresponds to success or that the operation is not yet done. What is the purpose of `AynchronousSocketChannel` and `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` then, apart from the callback functionalities?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> which can be set to non-blocking mode (asynchronous)

There's your misapprehension, right there. Non-blocking mode is *different* from asynchronous mode.

A non-blocking operation either transfers data or it doesn't. In either case there is no blocking, and the operation is complete once it returns. This mode is supported by `SocketChannel,` `DatagramSocketChannel,` and `Selector.`

An asynchronous operation starts when you call the method and continues in the background, with the result becoming available at a later time via a callback or a `Future`. This mode is supported by the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` etc classes you mention in your question.

Answer (score 6):

The [AynchronousSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html) and [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html) come into their own when using the methods that take a [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html).

For example the code in a server might look like this:

```
asynchronousServerSocketChannel.accept(Void, new ConnectionHander());
```

Where `ConnectionHander` is an implementation of [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) that deals with client connections.

The thread that makes the [accept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html#accept%28A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler%29) call can then continue doing other work and the NIO API will deal with scheduling the callback to the [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html) when a client connection is made (I believe this is an OS level interupt).

The alternative code, using a [ServerSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#accept--), might look like this:

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
```

Depending on the mode, the calling thread is now blocked until a client connection is made or `null` is returned leaving you to *poll*.  In both cases, it's you that has to deal with the threads, which generally means more work.

At the end of the day, you take your pick based on your particular use-case, though I've generally the former produces clearer more reliable code.

Comment: The same thing happens when using a `Future`. There is no 'comes into its own' about it. In both cases the operation continues asynchronously. The only difference is in the manner of discovering the result.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, I should have been clearer, the alternative is using `ServerSocketChannel` - I've updated accordingly.

Comment: No improvement. They 'come into their own' when using *either* a `Future` or a `CompletionHandler`: which is, trivially, to say 'use them at all'.